# How to animate an SVG circle dynamically given a list of values?

Tags: javascript, react-native, svg, react-native-svg

I have a list of values such as:

`[10, 20, 20, 30, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, ...]`

That can change before the animation starts.

The goal is to take an SVG circle and do the following:

- Index i = 0
- Smooth set radius to list[i] over X seconds
- Increase i
- Smooth set radius to list[i] over X seconds
- Increase i
- ...

I currently use `Animate.timing` and `onComplete` I start a new one but it seems like an inefficient way (and perhaps it can add some delays) to setup a pre-planned animation. Is there a way to tell the SVG object to change shape at given timings and given durations?

I am imagining to be able to tell the circle to:

`[{from_radius: 10, to_radius: 20, duration: 0.25}, {from_radius: 20, to_radius: 20, duration: 0.25}, {from_radius: 20, to_radius: 30, duration: 0.25}, ...]`

And give that to the circle to handle it automatically.

Comment: Sure, use SMIL.

Comment: @RobertLongson can you give me a small intro/snippet to get started with that? I never heard of SMIL and can't find anything with `react-native-svg`

Comment: https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/IG/resources/svgprimer.html#SMIL_animations assuming react-native-svg supports it.

Comment: Thanks @RobertLongson but that example seems to have a simple animation rather than taking the values from a list. I just wonder if it is possible.

Comment: Yes it's possible. Check out the [values attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/animate.html#ValueAttributes) there's some [examples in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/keyTimes)